# SQL Server how to pivot joint query

Tags: sql-server-2008, pivot

I have a query run join from different table:

```
select 
    b.first_name, d.client_fullname, a.plan_id, c.joint_info 
from 
    PLAN_INFO a 
inner join 
    JHI_USER b on a.created_by = b.login 
left join 
    PLAN_INFO_CLIENT c on c.plan_id = a.plan_id
                       and c.plan_id is not null
left join 
    CLIENT d on d.client_id = c.client_id
left join 
    CLIENT_ADDRESS_DET e on e.client_id = d.client_id 
order by 
    a.plan_id ASC
```

And this is the result

```
client_fullname | plan_id | joint_info
----------------+---------+------------
venus           | 992     | M
Ric             | 992     | J1
Ricardo         | 992     | J2
Hisa            | 992     | J3
```

M is primary, J1 is joint one, J2 is joint two, this record is for joint account to make it more clear.

I have a requirement to move my J2 name to be my 3rd column as this:

```
    client_fullname | plan_id | joint_name
    venus           | 992     | Ric
```

only j1 need to be show.

Tried to read the pivot example but kind of stuck here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use conditional aggregation for this.

```
SELECT MAX(CASE
               WHEN c.joint_info = 'M'
               THEN d.client_fullname
           END) AS client_fullname,
       a.plan_id,
       MAX(CASE
               WHEN c.joint_info = 'J1'
               THEN d.client_fullname
           END) AS joint_name
FROM   PLAN_INFO a
       INNER JOIN JHI_USER b ON a.created_by = b.login
       LEFT JOIN PLAN_INFO_CLIENT c ON c.plan_id = a.plan_id
                                       AND c.plan_id IS NOT NULL
       LEFT JOIN CLIENT d ON d.client_id = c.client_id
       LEFT JOIN CLIENT_ADDRESS_DET e ON e.client_id = d.client_id
GROUP BY a.plan_id
ORDER BY a.plan_id ASC;
```

Comment: this query works well with me, thank you sir got more column to go lol.. ty very2 much for the insight

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
WITH CTE AS (

    select b.first_name,d.client_fullname,a.plan_id,
     c.joint_info 
    from PLAN_INFO a 
    inner join JHI_USER b on  a.created_by = b.login
    left join PLAN_INFO_CLIENT c
    on c.plan_id =a.plan_id
    and c.plan_id is not null
    left join CLIENT d 
    on d.client_id =c.client_id
    left join CLIENT_ADDRESS_DET e
    on e.client_id = d.client_id 
    order by a.plan_id ASC
    )

    select client_fullname,plan_id,
    (select client_fullname  from cte b where a.plan_id=b.plan_id and 
    b.joint_info='J1') as joint_name  
    from cte a 
    where joint_info='M'
```

Comment: i remove the order by clauses inside CTE, and after that it throw sql error subquery returned more than 1 value